# BERT server does not start

Tags: python, bert-language-model

I successfully installed BERT server and client.
I tried to start server by typing following code in a Anaconda Prompt

```sh
bert-serving-start -model_dir C:\bert\uncased_L-24_H-1024_A-16 -num_worker=4
```

It supposed to print some responses if the server started properly as shown in https://github.com/hanxiao/bert-as-service#install.

However, in my case, nothing shows in the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

The following is how I fixed the problem.

1. uninstall bert-serving-server and bert-serving-client
2. create new virtual environment
3. downgrade python version to access lower version of tensorflow
4. download tensorflow1.15

5.install bert-serving-server and bert-serving-client
6.problem solved!!!